# Is it possible in Java to implement interfaces and their methods without using the keyword "implements"?

Tags: java, interface

I have homework to do (actually my girlfriend :-D) and there are some restrictions on what I can and can't do.
In my NetBeans project folder there are two folders named "interfaces" and "homework".
The folder "interfaces" contains interfaces and classes that are NOT allowed to edit, because said that to us xD.
I am only allowed to edit the source text in the "homework" folder.

Usually, I know it to implement interfaces in Java with the keyword "implements". But I don't know how to use it in the "homework" folder, because the "interfaces" folder already contains classes that implement the methods and logic of the interfaces, but I am not allowed to edit them.

This is the task:

"We provide you with various interfaces in the "interfaces" package, which you have to implement. You are only allowed to create your own implementation in the "homework" package. You may not modify the classes and interfaces of the "interfaces" package!

The interface "TextAdventure", the methods of which you have to implement, allow you to create a text adventure game. In the "homework" package you will find a Main class that uses the TextAdventure interface to initialize various games.
You can play through that game after you successfully implementing the interfaces as disired. The game scenarios are designed to help you extensively test your code. All methods of the Interface Player are available for interacting with the game. Also take a look at the GameStarter class. In this, the interaction with the player is implemented.

The TextAdventure interface offers various methods for creating a new game. For each method, think about the cases in which it could fail. In such cases, throw a TextAdventureException. This is also made available to you in the "interfaces" package. Once the desired initial state is established, a game can be started with "startGame ()"."

Interfaces:

```
package interfaces;

import homework.Factory;

/**
 * Class with text adventure scenarios to play.
 */
public class Adventures {

    /**
     * Initialize the fireman-game.
     *
     * @return the fireman-game
     * @throws TextAdventureException
     */
    public static interfaces.TextAdventure getFiremanGame() throws TextAdventureException {
        interfaces.TextAdventure textAdventure = Factory.getGame("Sample1", 2, 2);
        textAdventure.addSceneryType("BurningTree", "A blazing fire on an oak tree.");
        textAdventure.addSceneryType("HalfBurningTree", "A little fire on an oak tree.");
        textAdventure.addItemType("Bucket", "An empty bucket.");
        textAdventure.addItemType("Water", "A bucket full of water.");
        textAdventure.addItemType("Head", "Kopf");
        textAdventure.addItemType("Headweh", "Jetzt brummt de kopf");
        textAdventure.addSceneryType("Lake", "A beautiful lake.");
        textAdventure.addSceneryType("CharredOak", "A poor, charred oak tree.");
        textAdventure.addTransformation("Bucket", "Lake", "Water", "Lake",
                "Now you got a bucket full of water.");
        textAdventure.addTransformation("Water", "BurningTree", "HalfBurningTree", "Bucket",
                "The water quenches the fire. But not completely.");
        textAdventure.addTransformation("Water", "HalfBurningTree", "CharredOak", "Bucket",
                "The water quenches the fire.");
        textAdventure.addComposition("Bucket", "Head", "Headweh", "Kopfwehh");
        textAdventure.placeItem("Lake", 0, 0);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Bucket", 1, 1);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Head", 1, 1);
        textAdventure.placeItem("BurningTree", 0, 0);
        return textAdventure;
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the lumberjack-game.
     *
     * @return The lumberjack-game
     * @throws TextAdventureException
     */
    public static interfaces.TextAdventure getLumberjackGame() throws TextAdventureException {
        interfaces.TextAdventure textAdventure = Factory.getGame("Sample2", 1, 1);
        textAdventure.addSceneryType("Tree", "A lush green tree.");
        textAdventure.addItemType("Wood", "Some pieces of wood");
        textAdventure.addSceneryType("Roots", "The sad roots of a former tree.");
        textAdventure.addDecomposition("Tree", "Wood", "Roots", "You fell the tree and get some wood.");
        textAdventure.placeItem("Tree", 0, 0);
        return textAdventure;
    }


    /**
     * Initialize the pokemon-game.
     *
     * @return the pokemon-game
     * @throws TextAdventureException
     */
    public static interfaces.TextAdventure getPokemonGame() throws TextAdventureException {
        TextAdventure textAdventure = Factory.getGame("Pokemon", 50, 50);

        textAdventure.addItemType("Coin", "One coin");
        textAdventure.addItemType("Money", "Many coins");
        textAdventure.addItemType("Bisasam", "Look, a wild Bisasam.");
        textAdventure.addItemType("Glumanda", "Look, a wild Glumanda.");
        textAdventure.addItemType("Schiggy", "Look, a wild Schiggy.");
        textAdventure.addItemType("Bisaknosp", "Bisaknosp eats plants.");
        textAdventure.addItemType("Glutexo", "Glutexo burns.");
        textAdventure.addItemType("Schillok", "Schillok swimming around.");
        textAdventure.addItemType("Bisaflor", "Bisaflor eats plants.");
        textAdventure.addItemType("Glurak", "Glurak burns.");
        textAdventure.addItemType("Turtok", "Turtok swimming around.");
        textAdventure.addItemType("Taubsi", "Taubsi flying around.");
        textAdventure.addItemType("Tauboga", "Tauboga flying around.");
        textAdventure.addItemType("Tauboss", "Tauboss flying around.");
        textAdventure.addItemType("Mewtu", "Mewtu sees dead people.");
        textAdventure.addItemType("Developmentstone",
                "The Developmentstone brings your Pokemon to the next Level.");
        textAdventure.addItemType("Attackstone",
                "The Attackstone is in combination with your Pokemon to attack other Pokemons.");
        textAdventure.addItemType("Pokeball",
                "Pokeball is there to catch other Pokemons.");
        textAdventure.addSceneryType("Wildtaubsi", "Look, a wild Taubsi.");
        textAdventure.addSceneryType("Deadtaubsi", "Look, a dead Taubsi.");
        textAdventure.addSceneryType("Silvertreasure", "Look, a Treasure.");
        textAdventure.addSceneryType("Goldtreasure", "Look, a Treasure.");
        textAdventure.placeItem("Coin", 0, 0);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Bisasam", 0, 0);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Glumanda", 0, 0);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Schiggy", 0, 0);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Developmentstone", 2, 4);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Developmentstone", 25, 31);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Developmentstone", 49, 11);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Developmentstone", 22, 22);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Developmentstone", 11, 44);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Developmentstone", 23, 43);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Developmentstone", 39, 1);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Developmentstone", 22, 21);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Developmentstone", 45, 30);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Developmentstone", 10, 12);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Developmentstone", 23, 1);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Developmentstone", 49, 49);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Developmentstone", 17, 15);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Attackstone", 1, 1);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Attackstone", 10, 10);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Attackstone", 20, 20);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Attackstone", 30, 30);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Attackstone", 4, 5);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Attackstone", 10, 2);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Attackstone", 23, 44);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Attackstone", 30, 35);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Pokeball", 1, 1);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Pokeball", 3, 22);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Pokeball", 17, 21);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Pokeball", 33, 13);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Pokeball", 45, 22);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Pokeball", 21, 13);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Pokeball", 19, 41);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Pokeball", 12, 32);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Wildtaubsi", 2, 2);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Wildtaubsi", 23, 24);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Wildtaubsi", 11, 7);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Wildtaubsi", 3, 9);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Wildtaubsi", 32, 45);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Wildtaubsi", 31, 29);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Wildtaubsi", 17, 31);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Wildtaubsi", 45, 45);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Wildtaubsi", 18, 32);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Wildtaubsi", 26, 42);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Wildtaubsi", 42, 26);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Wildtaubsi", 17, 49);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Wildtaubsi", 11, 22);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Wildtaubsi", 36, 39);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Wildtaubsi", 31, 24);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Silvertreasure", 2, 3);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Silvertreasure", 32, 33);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Silvertreasure", 14, 13);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Silvertreasure", 47, 11);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Silvertreasure", 12, 34);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Silvertreasure", 21, 33);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Silvertreasure", 43, 21);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Silvertreasure", 49, 3);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Silvertreasure", 12, 49);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Silvertreasure", 41, 34);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Silvertreasure", 12, 33);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Silvertreasure", 22, 34);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Silvertreasure", 1, 40);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Silvertreasure", 19, 28);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Silvertreasure", 45, 32);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Silvertreasure", 21, 23);
        textAdventure.placeItem("Goldtreasure", 33, 34);
        textAdventure.addComposition("Coin", "Coin", "Money", "You made money");
        textAdventure.addComposition("Bisasam", "Developmentstone", "Bisaknosp",
                "Look your Bisasam has developed to Bisaknosp.");
        textAdventure.addComposition("Glumanda", "Developmentstone", "Glutexo",
                "Look your Glumanda has developed to Glutexo.");
        textAdventure.addComposition("Schiggy", "Developmentstone", "Schillok",
                "Look your Schiggy has developed to Schillok.");
        textAdventure.addComposition("Taubsi", "Developmentstone", "Tauboga",
                "Look your Taubsi has developed to Tauboga");
        textAdventure.addComposition("Bisaknosp", "Developmentstone", "Bisaflor",
                "Look your Bisaknosp has developed to Bisaflor");
        textAdventure.addComposition("Glutexo", "Developmentstone", "Glurak",
                "Look your Glutexo has developed to Glurak");
        textAdventure.addComposition("Schillok", "Developmentstone", "Turtok",
                "Look your Schillok has developed to Turtok");
        textAdventure.addComposition("Tauboga", "Developmentstone", "Tauboss",
                "Look your Tauboga has developed to Tauboss");
        textAdventure.addComposition("Wildtaubsi", "Attackstone", "Deadtaubsi",
                "Your Pokemon attacks the wild Taubsi. Taubsi is dead.");
        textAdventure.addComposition("Wildtaubsi", "Pokeball", "Taubsi",
                "You have catch Taubsi. Congratulations, Taubsi is your new Pokemon.");
        textAdventure.addDecomposition("Silvertreasure", "Developmentstone",
                "Attackstone",
                "You open the treasure and you find an Attack- and Developmentstone.");
        textAdventure.addDecomposition("Goldtreasure", "Pokeball", "Mewtu",
                "See, you find the unique Mewtu.");
        textAdventure.addTransformation("Taubsi", "Attackstone", "Taubsi",
                "Developmentstone",
                "Look, your Taubsi transform the Attackstone to a Developmentstone.");
        textAdventure.addTransformation("Tauboga", "Attackstone", "Tauboga",
                "Developmentstone",
                "Look, your Tauboga transform the Attackstone to a Developmentstone.");
        textAdventure.addTransformation("Tauboss", "Attackstone", "Tauboss",
                "Developmentstone",
                "Look, your Tauboss transform the Attackstone to a Developmentstone.");
        textAdventure.addTransformation("Mewtu", "Developmentstone", "Mewtu",
                "Attackstone",
                "Look, your Mewtu transform the Developmentstone to a Attackstone.");
        textAdventure.addTransformation("Bisasam", "Attackstone", "Bisasam",
                "Pokeball",
                "Look, your Bisasam transform the Attackstone to a Pokeball.");
        textAdventure.addTransformation("Bisaknosp", "Attackstone", "Bisaknosp",
                "Pokeball",
                "Look, your Bisaknosp transform the Attackstone to a Pokeball.");
        textAdventure.addTransformation("Bisaflor", "Attackstone", "Bisaflor",
                "Pokeball",
                "Look, your Bisaflor transform the Attackstone to a Pokeball.");
        textAdventure.addTransformation("Glumanda", "Pokeball", "Glumanda",
                "Developmentstone",
                "Look, your Glumanda transform the Pokeball to a Developmentstone.");
        textAdventure.addTransformation("Glutexo", "Pokeball", "Glutexo",
                "Developmentstone",
                "Look, your Glutexo transform the Pokeball to a Developmentstone.");
        textAdventure.addTransformation("Glurak", "Pokeball", "Glurak",
                "Developmentstone",
                "Look, your Glurak transform the Pokeball to a Developmentstone.");
        textAdventure.addTransformation("Schiggy", "Pokeball", "Schiggy",
                "Attackstone",
                "Look, your Schiggy transform the Pokeball to a Attackstone.");
        textAdventure.addTransformation("Schillok", "Pokeball", "Schillok",
                "Attackstone",
                "Look, your Schillok transform the Pokeball to a Attackstone.");
        textAdventure.addTransformation("Turtok", "Pokeball", "Turtok",
                "Attackstone",
                "Look, your Turtok transform the Pokeball to a Attackstone.");

        return textAdventure;
    }
}

package interfaces;

import homework.Factory;

/**
 * Class integrates the implementation of the student package and allows to play the text adventure scenarios.
 */
public class GameStarter {

    private static final String PROMPT = "play>";
    private static Player player;
    private Terminal terminal;
    private TextAdventure[] games;

    /**
     * Constructor to create a GameStarter instance.
     * @param games array with text adventures games to play
     */
    public GameStarter(TextAdventure[] games) {
        terminal = Factory.getTerminal();
        this.games = games;
    }

    /**
     * Starts one of the given games.
     */
    public void startGame() {
        String[] input;
        String prompt = "Play (";
        for (TextAdventure game : this.games) {
            prompt += game.getName();
            prompt += "|";
        }
        prompt = prompt.substring(0, prompt.length() - 1) + ")";
        do {
            terminal.promptInput(prompt);
            input = terminal.readInput();
        } while (input[0].equals("") || input[0].equals(" "));


        String gameName = input[0];
        for (TextAdventure game : this.games) {
            if (game.getName().equals(gameName)) {
                startGame(game, 0, 0);
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Unknown game scenario");
        System.exit(1);


    }

    /**
     * Starts a given game and runs a simple input-loop that accepts game-commands.
     * @param textAdventure to play
     * @param x coordinate of the player
     * @param y coordinate of the player
     */
    public void startGame(TextAdventure textAdventure, int x, int y) {
        try {
            player = textAdventure.startGame(x, y);
        } catch (TextAdventureException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        boolean run = true;
        while (run) {
            try {
                terminal.promptInput(PROMPT);
                String[] input = terminal.readInput();
                run = processInput(input);
            } catch (TextAdventureException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Process the given command-line, translate it into player-actions if possible.
     * @param input the splitted user input
     * @return false if the user wants to quit, true otherwise
     * @throws TextAdventureException If an invalid command is entered
     */
    private static boolean processInput(String[] input) throws TextAdventureException {
        switch (input[0]) {
            case "go": {
                if (input.length < 2) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, please specify a direction.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(player.go(input[1]));
                }
                return true;
            }
            case "look": {
                String[] list = player.look();
                for (String line : list) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                return true;
            }
            case "inventory": {
                String[] list = player.inventory();
                for (String line : list) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
                return true;
            }
            case "take": {
                if (input.length < 2) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, please specify an object.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(player.take(input[1]));
                }
                return true;
            }
            case "drop": {
                if (input.length < 2) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, please specify an object.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(player.drop(input[1]));
                }
                return true;
            }
            case "convert": {
                if (input.length < 3) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, please specify the objects to compose.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(player.convert(input[1], input[2]));
                }
                return true;
            }
            case "decompose": {
                if (input.length < 2) {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, please specify an object.");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(player.decompose(input[1]));
                }
                return true;
            }
            case "help": {
                System.out.println("Valid Commands are: go, look, inventory, take, drop, compose, decompose");
                return true;
            }
            case "exit": {
                System.out.println("Bye!");
                return false;
            }
            default: {
                throw new TextAdventureException("Unknown Command: " + input[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}


package interfaces;

/**
 * Models the interface of a text adventure player.
 */
public interface Player {

    /**
     * Move the player's token into direction.
     * @param direction One of eight valid directions "N", "NE", "E", "SE", "S", "SW", "W", "NW"
     * @return A ui-message for the user
     */
    String go(String direction);

    /**
     * Returns an array of objects on the current field.
     * @return An array of object-type and descriptions for the ui
     */
    String[] look();
    
    /**
     * Returns an array of objects in the inventory.
     * @return An array of object-type and descriptions for the ui
     */
    String[] inventory();

    /**
     * Removes an object of the given type from the current field and adds it to the inventory.
     * @param item An object-type
     * @return A ui-message for the user
     */
    String take(String item);
    
    /**
     * Removes an object of the given type from the inventory and adds it to the current field.
     * @param item An object-type
     * @return A ui-message for the user
     */
    String drop(String item);

    /**
     * Applies a transformation- or composition-rule to item1 and item2. 
     * If possible, removes item1 and item2 from the current field or inventory 
     * and adds the mutation-result to the current field or inventory,
     * depending on the object's base-type (scenery or item). 
     * @param item1 An Object-Type
     * @param item2 An Object-Type
     * @return A ui-message for the user
     */
    String convert(String item1, String item2);
    
    /**
     * Applies a decomposition-rule to item. 
     * If possible, removes item from the current field or inventory 
     * and adds the mutation-result to the current field or inventory,
     * depending on the object's base-type (scenery or item). 
     * @param item An Object-Type
     * @return A ui-message for the user
     */
    String decompose(String item);
}

package interfaces;

/**
 * Models the interface of terminal to interact with a player.
 */
public interface Terminal {

    /**
     * Prompts the user to enter a string as input. The string is printed to the standard output (terminal).
     *
     * @param input the message to display the player
     */
    public void promptInput(String input);

    /**
     * Reads the user input and returns splitted at spaces as string array.
     * @return splitted user input string
     */
    public String[] readInput();

} 

package interfaces;

/**
 * Models the interface of a text adventure game-instance.
 */
public interface TextAdventure {

    /**
     * Declares a new portable object-type with given id and description.
     * @param id The id object-type, used in the ui to search for objects
     * @param description The description of the object-type
     * @throws TextAdventureException Think about the cases in which an exception is useful and implement it.
     */
    void addItemType(String id, String description) throws TextAdventureException;
    
    /**
     * Declares a new non-portable object-type with given id and description.
     * @param id The id object-type, used in the ui to search for objects
     * @param description The description of the object-type
     * @throws TextAdventureException Think about the cases in which an exception is useful and implement it.
     */
    void addSceneryType(String id, String description) throws TextAdventureException;

    /**
     * Adds a new object of the given type to the field at the specified position.
     * @param type The id of an object-type
     * @param x A field coordinate on the board
     * @param y A field coordinate on the board
     * @throws TextAdventureException Think about the cases in which an exception is useful and implement it.
     */
    void placeItem(String type, int x, int y) throws TextAdventureException;

    /**
     * Adds a new composition-rule to the set of mutation-rules.
     * @param in1 Object-type id of the input-object
     * @param in2 Object-type id of the input-object
     * @param out Object-type id of the output-object
     * @param description Mutation-description for the ui
     * @throws TextAdventureException Think about the cases in which an exception is useful and implement it.
     */
    void addComposition(String in1, String in2, String out, String description) throws TextAdventureException;
    
    /**
     * Adds a new decomposition-rule to the set of mutation-rules.
     * @param in Object-type id of the input-object
     * @param out1 Object-type id of the output-object
     * @param out2 Object-type id of the output-object
     * @param description Mutation-description for the ui
     * @throws TextAdventureException Think about the cases in which an exception is useful and implement it.
     */
    void addDecomposition(String in, String out1, String out2, String description) throws TextAdventureException;
    
    /**
     * Adds a new transformation-rule to the set of mutation-rules.
     * @param in1 in1 Object-type id of the input-object
     * @param in2 in1 Object-type id of the input-object
     * @param out1 Object-type id of the output-object
     * @param out2 Object-type id of the output-object
     * @param description Mutation-description for the ui
     * @throws TextAdventureException Think about the cases in which an exception is useful and implement it.
     */
    void addTransformation(String in1, String in2, String out1, String out2, String description)
            throws TextAdventureException;

    /**
     * Initializes a new game instance and returns a player-instance for game-control. 
     * The player's initial position is at the given coordinates
     * @param x A field coordinate on the board
     * @param y A field coordinate on the board
     * @return A player-instance for game-control
     * @throws TextAdventureException Think about the cases in which an exception is useful and implement it.
     */
    Player startGame(int x, int y) throws TextAdventureException;

    /**
     * Returns the name of the game instance.
     * @return the name of the game instance
     */
    String getName();
}

package interfaces;

/**
 * General Exception-type of the text adventure framework.
 */
public class TextAdventureException extends Exception {

    /**
     * Exception Prefix.
     */
    public static final String ERROR = "Error! ";

    /**
     * Creates a new TextAdventureException with the given message.
     * @param message The error-message
     */
    public TextAdventureException(String message) {
        super(ERROR + message);
    }
}

package homework;

/**
 * Factory class with functions to generate a game and terminal.
 */
public final class Factory {
    
    private Factory() { }
        
    public static interfaces.TextAdventure getGame(String name, int boardWidth, int boardHeight)
            throws interfaces.TextAdventureException {
        //placeholder
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new terminal-instance to read user input and prompt messages.
     * @return a terminal instance
     */ 
    public static interfaces.Terminal getTerminal() {
        //placeholder
        return null;
    }
}
```

package homework;
public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // Add additional games to the Array
        TextAdventure[] games = {
                Adventures.getFiremanGame(), Adventures.getLumberjackGame(), Adventures.getPokemonGame()
        };
        GameStarter starter = new GameStarter(games);
        starter.startGame();
    } catch (TextAdventureException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Your characterization of the exercise doesn't seem to match the code you've presented.  As far as I can tell, the classes in the `interfaces` package do not provide anything like implementations of the interfaces in question (`Player`, `Terminal`, and `TextAdventure`).  Rather, they *use* implementations of those interfaces, which they obtain by invoking various static methods of class `homework.Factory`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I had to make an browser update because I couldn't write no comments oder editing my question. The are some missing parts, you are right. :-D

Comment: Are you going to do your girlfriend's job interviews too?  Seriously, doing her homework for her will make you feel good, but won't actually help her to learn ... or pass her exams ... or get her a job that needs programming skills.

Comment: @StephenC well, it sounds like the OP is learning how to do these things himself at this point, too. Sometimes people sit down and work in groups. I think you told them to be careful about that setup, that should be good enough.

Comment: She just didn't want to register here. Too many passwords to remember. xD

Also, I don't do my girlfriend's homework. I just want to help her, but I don't understand it myself xD.

Comment: Two things: learn what the concept of packages is about in Java. Just thinking in "folders" isn't sufficient. Then: never provide more information into comments, especially not code. Edit the question instead. But in your case, you have almost too much input already. You have to understand that dumping a complete homework assignment with "now what?" does not constitute a valid question just by itself.

Comment: The point of such assignments is often that you need to sit down and look at many things and just talk about that. But this community is about specific programming questions. You should rather look to work with other students or some tutor....

Comment: Sorry, you are right GhostCat. But I have bad eyes und it is very hard for me to read this stuff. This websites has a bad design (for eye-disabled people). Posting code in comments was not my itention. But I can't see a delete button xD.

Comment: Note: you did actually say *"I have homework to do (actually my girlfriend :-D)"*.  You may have misspoken ... but those ARE your words.

Comment: I have written in the "I-form" but I mean she. xD

Comment: Hovering the mouse pointer at the right position there is indeed a delete button xD. Thanks man.

Comment: Why can't you use "implements" or "extends"? Is there an error when you do?

Comment: Regarding this question: it doesn't have down votes, so others will probably not vote for deletion. It isn't a great question, but also not a terrible one. I would just keep it around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement all the methods that an interface X declares without writing "implements X". But that is really nonsensical. You want that the Java compiler understands that your new class implements X. And you need that keyword on the signature of the class definition for that.

One could think of extending a class that already implements an interface, then you don't have to repeat the keyword "implements X". But that is really just about not using that keyword in your source code.

In your case, the key part is to understand that not **all** interfaces in that *package interfaces* have an implementation so far. Your starting point: write down just the list of names of classes and interfaces that exist in the input you received. Then see which interface has implementations, and which have not!

Comment: Yes, in this case if I use the keyword "implements" I have to have that methods in that class. But the teacher says that the game and the logic is already finished.

Comment: So maybe I just don't understand the homework / task. :-(

Comment: Again: not all classes are implemented so far. Read my answer again. Read the comments again that you got from others. That really tells you all the things you need to start.

Comment: Thanks, GhostCat. Me and my girlfriend made it.

Comment: But what should I do now ? Here is a message "This question needs to be more focused." Should I delete this question now, because it is too broad or should I mark your answer as the right or most helpful answer ? I don't know :-(